# Error in Glance_image[cirros] : change from absent to present failed: Command: ... has been running for more then 20 seconds

Tags: centos, puppet, openstack, rdo

I am running packstack.

> Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Glance_image[cirros]/ensure: change from
>   absent to pres
>   ent failed: Command: 'openstack ["image", "create", "--format",
>   "shell", ["cirros", "--public", "--container-format=bare", "--disk-format=qcow2", "--copy-from=http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.4/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-disk.img"]]' has been running for more then 20 seconds!

I am having this error, I can wget it though, so I can perfectly reach it. Can someone help me resolving this? As a workaround I tried it manually, but I am really new to centos and Openstack, so I don't know much. I tried :

`openstack image create --format shell cirros --public --container-format=bare --disk-format=qcow2 --copy-from=http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.4/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-disk.img`

> I got Missing parameter(s):
>
> Set a username with --os-username, OS_USERNAME, or auth.username Set
>   an authentication URL, with --os-auth-url, OS_AUTH_URL or
>   auth.auth_url Set a scope, such as a project or domain, set a project
>   scope with --os-project-
>   name, OS_PROJECT_NAME or auth.project_name, set a domain scope with
>   --os-domain-name, OS_DOMAIN_NAME or auth.domain_name

What should I add to the above command? Will it be able to solve my problem? If not what is the right way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by replacing 
`--copy-from=http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.4/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-disk.img` to point `--copy-from=<local path>` 
But didn't got why the original command not working even when I can wget it.

Comment: Does your traffic to the outside need to go through a proxy server?  Are you perhaps providing the address of the proxy server via an environment variable?  Even if you're running `puppet apply`, but especially if you're running `puppet agent`, the commands Puppet executes on your behalf run in a minimal environment by default.  In that case, you may be interested in http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2013/10/configuring-puppet-conf-to-support-a-proxy-server.html.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that helps with Execs, though.  You may need to look for a way to specify proxy server information to the `glance_image` type.